# Cross Database Join in Bonobo using bonobo_sqlalchemy (ETL)

Tags: python, etl, bonobo-etl

I've been trying to join different data sources (MySQL and PostgreSQL) in Bonobo, but I've been struggling so far to deal with paralelism  and if bonobo is the most adequate tool to do that

I know I can fetch Bonobo data with such

```
def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(
        bonobo_sqlalchemy.Select('SELECT * FROM table', limit=100, engine='psql'),
        ...,
    )

    return graph
```

But what is really desirable in my situation atm is to join this fetch with another data, found in another table (this could be potentially a join in dask/pandas)

I know I can fetch Bonobo data with such

```
def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(
        bonobo_sqlalchemy.Select('SELECT * FROM table', limit=100, engine='psql'),
        fetch_mysql_and_join_data,
        ...,
    )

    return graph
```

In my perspective this has two issues:

1. It doesn't make sense to join tables like that in a parallel/distributed fetch like bonobo;
2. bonobo implementation of sqlalchemy is built to work with multiprocessing/threading;

How could I make it work? Should I move to another tool?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding myself with a similar problem with an inherited Bonobo ETL project. For me two possible solutions have come to mind:

1. Within the second step of the chain you may be able to fetch each related entity from your MySQL service, "join" or merge the data as needed, and yield it to the next node.
2. Forego the use of the reader provided by `bonobo_sqlalchemy`, inject both 'mysql' & 'psql' services into your initial extraction transformation, and do your fetching / joining yourself.

The first approach would be the easiest to implement, but it would produce N+1 selects and may be intolerably slow. The second approach could prove to be more performant, but it may also require you to manage your data streams yourself if you're dealing with large enough data sets.